# A better return type than object for classes derived from an interface

Tags: c#

I have a class with an `IDataProcessor` type variable.

```
class MyClass
{
    IDataProcessor _processor;
    ...
}

public interface IDataProcessor
{
    object Process(int a, int b);
}
```

and some implementations

```
class IntDataProcessor : IDataProcessor
{
    public object Process(int a, int b)
    {
        return (int) (a + b);
    }
}

class DoubleDataProcessor : IDataProcessor
{
    public object Process(int a, int b)
    {
        return (double) (a + b);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the `object` return type?

**P.S.**: The actual functionality of the `Process` methods is more complex than I've let on here. For instance, the `DoubleDataProcessor` actually converts the two integers into a double.

Comment: Well, what you should return (probably another interface) depends on what the interface is supposed to be for, which you haven't detailed at all.

Comment: What's an issue with `object` return type? It makes perfect sense here.

Comment: So far it doesn't look like you need a wrapper interface for these kind of operations, they are to specific, a converter class would be more appropriate and if you do need it to be generic than as AntP indicates, you could return an interface in your 'converter/processor' class.

Comment: @RohitVats It has a funny smell of misusing the strategy pattern. Also the `Process` is iterated over a large array so there is some, perhaps noticable, extra boxing/unboxing overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Generics.

Change your interface to this:

```
public interface IDataProcessor<T>
{
    T Process(T a, T b);
}
```

and then the two others to this:

```
class IntDataProcessor : IDataProcessor<int>
{
    public int Process(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

class DoubleDataProcessor : IDataProcessor<double>
{
    public double Process(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think generics are appropriate without more context? Another strongly-typed interface would probably do just fine. This looks ugly to me.

Comment: But as what should `IDataProcessor` type variable in my main class be declared?

Comment: @lejon whatever you need it to be. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: With generics you are in fact creating multiple interfaces, just with less writing. That may or may not be applicable here. After the question-edit: NOT.

Comment: @AntP The type will be known from another parameter. The problem with generics is that I cannot have a `IDataProcessor` that gets instantiated as a `ConcreteDataProcessor<T>`.

Comment: Generics, because you won't be going through boxing and unboxing which generally should be avoided.

Comment: @lejon unless `MyClass` is generic too. In a `MyClass<T>` you can have a `IDataProcessor<T>` that gets instantiated as a `ConcreteDataProcessor<T>`. If each `MyClass` is dealing with only one type of processor (say `IDataProcessor<int>`) it could make sense to create it as a `MyClass<int>`.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella The sad omitted truth is that I have a MyClass collection, which then would have to contain MyClass of mixed return values, which is not possible. I have omitted this part in my question. Maybe I shouldn't have.

Comment: @lejon what do you do with the collection of MyClasses at the end? Is the fact that you have ints and doubles hidden inside MyClass or do you still need to cast the objects returned from Process to the original type?